# Angular testing with interval()

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-test

In my `ngOnInit` I check a route, do some stuff, and then setup an `interval`

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routeSubscription = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(x => {
         ...
         // Reload the data every 60 seconds
         interval(60_000)
             .pipe(takeUntil(this.cancelInterval$))
             .subscribe(() => this.rows$ = this.orderService.active())
    })
}
```

When I try to do my unit testing, jasmine aborts because the async method didn't return fast enough.  I'm doing this (as a sub-describe of the main one, which does all the normal `TestBed` setups):

```js
describe('when showing active orders', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        activatedRoute.setParamMap({})
        fixture.detectChanges()
    })

    it('...', async () => {
        await fixture.whenStable()
        ...
    })
```

It seems to be stuck because of the interval.  I thought I could just put a call to `discardPeriodicTasks()` at the end of the `beforeEach` method, but that doesn't work.

So I'm looking for either the right way to handle this in testing, or a way in the production code to only make the interval call if it's not being run via testing.

Angular CLI: 9.0.7
Node: 14.4.0
Angular: 9.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fakeAsync](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) and tick to simulate the async behaviour

`it('...',  fakeAsync () => { tick(60000); doTestStuff(); })`

Comment: This won't work, in my understanding. The problem with interval() is that it continuously schedules the next timeout and unit-test framework waits forever till all open timeouts finish.

Comment: well, I'd expect a ngOnDestroy on the component which will close the intervall (this.cancelInterval$) on the component & be called after successful assertion..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling RXJS `interval()` directly, create a simple intermediate service like this one:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TimerService {

  interval(ms: number) {
      return interval(ms);
  }

}
```

Inject and use it within your component: `timer.interval(60_000)`

Now it is trivial to mock the necessary behavior of the `interval()` within your unit-tests, e.g.:

```
providers: [{ provide: TimerService, useValue: { interval: () => of(1) } }],
```